# Jersey UniformInterfaceException when doing a POST with docker-client

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, uri, docker

When trying to post a RESTful Service via docker-client to my private docker registry i get that error. The confusing thing about that is that the input stream changes itself as you can see here. Its made somewhere in the background of jersey but i cannot find the cause for it. I guess the problem occurs somewhere inside the jersey logic

**Method**

```
public static Service initService(String imageId) {

        final com.spotify.docker.client.DockerClient docker = new DefaultDockerClient(
                "http://10.###.###.143:2375");
        String s = null;

        try {

            s = ("10.###.###.143:5000/user/ipatest&tag=latest");

            docker.pull(s);

            System.out.println(docker.toString());

        } catch (DockerException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Exception**

```
com.spotify.docker.client.DockerRequestException: Request error: POST http://10.###.###.143:2375/v1.12/images/create?fromImage=10.###.###.143%3A5000%2Fuser%2Fipatest%26tag%3Dlatest: 500
            at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.propagate(DefaultDockerClient.java:563)
            at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:544)
            at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.pull(DefaultDockerClient.java:345)
            at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.pull(DefaultDockerClient.java:329)
            at de.fhg.ipa.vfk.eapps.commoniaas.docker.DockerServiceMgmt.initService(DockerServiceMgmt.java:43)
            at de.fhg.ipa.vfk.eapps.commoniaas.docker.DockerServiceMgmt.main(DockerServiceMgmt.java:163)
        Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://10.###.###.143:2375/v1.12/images/create?fromImage=10.###.###.143%3A5000%2Fuser%2Fipatest%26tag%3Dlatest returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:688)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.method(WebResource.java:623)
            at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:540)
            ... 4 more
```

It must have something to do with queryParams(String params) which belongs to WebResource (jersey)

Comment: Do you have access to server log?

Comment: no i don´t sorry. it replaces something somewhere but i cant locate it

Comment: Do you know where your service is running to which you are posting the data?

Comment: service is running on an ubuntu machine with the newest docker 1.30 version BUT via console " curl -XPOST http://10.###.###.143:2375/v1.12/images/create? fromImage=10.###.###.143:5000/ipatest/latest
" this command is working

Comment: problem is fixed by docker-client lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image name you're passing to `pull` isn't valid. The format for an image name is `name:tag`. Do this instead:

```
docker.pull("10.###.###.143:5000/user/ipatest:latest");
```

Alternatively, you can ommit the `:latest`, since it is implied when no other tag is specified.